# Receive data from multiple wireless sensors simultaneously

Tags: sensors, bluetooth, wifi, xbee, accelerometer

I want to receive data from multiple (2/3) wireless sensors at the 512 Hz data rate simultaneously at a single receiver (bluetooth or any other wireless standard). Is it possible with one receiver or I need  multiple receivers?

I am novice to wireless communication please guide me to any available resources.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do this with Zigbee. The API mode in the Xbee modules enables this.

Unlike the AT mode in Zigbee the API mode enables you to distinguish between the packets that you receive from different slaves.

In the API mode, you send each data packet with as a frame with a header which contains start delimiter byte, most significant byte (which tells where the start byte is at), least significant byte (which tells the end of the byte), an API identifier, the data that you want to send and a checksum byte.

This link provides a nice tutorial which shows how to setup Xbees on API mode with an Arduino and Python:
http://serdmanczyk.github.io/XBeeAPI-PythonArduino-Tutorial/

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you @MayBee for your answer. I went through the link and found useful. Since I am at the design phase right now, I would like to know whether it is possible with wifi or bluetooth? I don't have any power constraints , also I want to know, since data is coming at 512 Hz from each sensor(3 sensors) what type of issues which may occur while synchronizing all the sensors? thank you.

Comment: One issue that I faced was that the XBee modules could not handle large data packets in the API mode. Usually, Bluetooth only allows one to one communication but I believe that there are certain modules that will allow multiple slaves. In the case of WiFi, you could perhaps set up an external server and the modules could communicate using that. I have done this for a paid of RNXV WiFly module.  But, you should be able to add more slaves to this without issues. If you want a personal area network with multiple nodes, Zigbee would be the easiest to work with.